# Is there a way to construct more/deeper layer of subsection?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, cells, stylesheet

We know in a notebook there are Sections, Subsections and Subsubsections. I wonder is there a way to construct something like Subsubsubsection and Subsubsubsub...subsection?

I ask this because when I do research, I write code and notes in one notebook. The contains in my notebook file accumulates day by day and makes it large and complex. Once I need to expand one of my subsubsection, I found that there is no deeper section layers so I have to lay out the added contain unorganized. I wonder is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Default.nb styles define them up to `"Subsubsubsubsection"` so you have two more levels to go.

They are not included in the Format>Style menu but you can use shortcuts. Hit Tab/Backspace to navigate down/up in section level. (coursor needs to be a the beginning of the cell).

If you need more you can define/edit a custom stylesheet and add there style analogous to:

```
Cell[StyleData["Section-5"],

 CellMargins->{{66, Inherited}, {2, 10}}, (*edit 66 if you need more indentation*)

 StyleKeyMapping->{
     (*remember to edit Subsubsubsubsection if you want `Tab` to move to Section-5*)
   "Backspace" -> "Subsubsubsubsection"        
 , KeyEvent["Tab", Modifiers -> {Shift}] -> "Section-6" (*if defined*)
 },

 CellGroupingRules->{"SectionGrouping", 70+10}, (*increment 10 for each deeper level*)

 FontColor->RGBColor[0.5, 0.01`, 0.], (*whatever you want*)

 MenuSortingValue->None, (*make it a number if you want it to appear in Format>Style menu*)
 
 PageBreakBelow->False,
 LanguageCategory->"NaturalLanguage",
 CounterIncrements->"Subsubsubsubsection",
 CounterAssignments->{{"Item", 0}, {"Subitem", 0}, {"Subsubitem", 0}, {"ItemNumbered", 0}, { "SubitemNumbered", 0}, {"SubsubitemNumbered", 0}}, 
 FontFamily->"Source Sans Pro",
 FontSize->14
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not figure out how the tab/backspace thing from Kuba's answer is working. But in Mathematica 13.2 you can click the plus that appears once you click in an empty cell, then choose *Other style of text* which opens a prompt. In the prompt you still cannot select the Subsubsubsection BUT you can simply type it in there and it will process it accordingly.